# How can I make an XSLT expression that gets the maximum datetime value?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm writing an XSLT to process this file:
http://www.unimod.org/xml/unimod.xml

I want to find the most recent date_time_modified attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This simple XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:umod="http://www.unimod.org/xmlns/schema/unimod_2"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/umod:modifications/umod:mod">
    <xsl:sort select="@date_time_modified" order="descending"/>

    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
     <xsl:value-of select="@date_time_modified"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the XML document contained at**: **http://www.unimod.org/xml/unimod.xml** (the document has almost 23000 lines and is unsuitable for including inline)...

**produces the wanted, correct result (latest modified date):**

```
2012-02-15 12:08:24
```

**Do note**: No special manipulation of the date string is required (even converting to number), because in this specific case the date is in "good" format and can be simply sorted as string.